How to display an image (picture) inside PHP using Docker bind mounts
I'm trying to upload an image using the img tag in PHP.
I'm using Docker with bind mounts (read and write permission) for a non-root user for my upload folder in Docker. My image still isn't showing up. The $path variable is showing as "../upload/ferrari_logo.php" but it doesn't seem to display the image after using the move_uploaded_file function in PHP.
How can I get the image to properly show up in the "about_me_img" tag?
mypage.php
<div class="photo_column">
<form method="post" id="upload_form" action="mypage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="about_me_photo">

    <?php
        $message = '';
        $moved = false;

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            if ($_FILES['photo_upload']['error'] === 0) {
                $temp = $_FILES['photo_upload']['tmp_name'];
                $path = '../upload/' . $_FILES['photo_upload']['name'];
                $moved = move_uploaded_file($temp, $path);
            } 

            if ($moved === true) {
                echo '<img id="about_me_img" src="' . $path . '"alt="">';
            } else {
                echo '<img id="about_me_img" src="" alt="">';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<img id="about_me_img" src="" alt="">';
        }

    ?>
            <div class="about_me_row">
                <input type="file" id="photo_upload" name="photo_upload" accept="image/*">
                <input type="submit" class="mypage_button"  id="submit_photo" value="Upload">
            </div>
            
        
    </div>
</form>
</div>

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  php-apache:
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    build: './build/php'
    volumes:
      - ./app/public:/var/www/html
      - ./src:/var/www/src
      - ./config:/var/www/config
      - ./upload:/var/www/upload
      - ./img:/var/www/img
    command: /bin/sh -c "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/upload && apache2-foreground"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    build: './build/mysql'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "commune"
    volumes:
      - dbData:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
volumes:
  app:
  src:
  config:
  upload:
  img:
  dbData:


can't see the user is set in the composition and the sudo chmod therein also looks fishy, so it's not that a surprise things won't work (skill issues). for the intermediate problem - ./img:/var/www/hrml/img could already suffice (with html/), but I've not looked specifically.

Yeah, I'm still transmitting from XAMPP to Docker so I'm trying to learn enough so I can go back to coding in PHP.  I think the issue lies in the paths and the bind mounts in Docker. Thank you

if you want a kickstart in a docker/compose based world for PHP apps, one option is ddev: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I fixed it. I had the wrong paths in Docker. I changed ./upload:/var/www/upload to ./app/public/upload:var/www/upload and now it works. Thanks again.

go for it, that's the spirit. And write this as an answer below, that will also show other users who have similar configuration problems how you've done that. this is a common problem with docker setup btw. and writing it down once your own and posting it on SO you can keep that online and it helps remembering it.

Yeah, this will definitely help the next person to take a closer look at their code. Thanks again.

I had the wrong paths in Docker. I changed ./upload:/var/www/upload to ./app/public/upload:var/www/upload and now it works.
My folder structure is:

app
public

index.php
img
upload


build
config
src
upload (duplicate folder)

I didn't receive a destination error because I had a duplicate upload folder outside the app folder, which I just deleted.
EDIT: Also, I meant "transitioning" not transmitting in the comments but can't edit.
